# SQLite select is one of List values

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to make a  query  and the select should be :

```
String select =  Contacts._ID + " = " + ids.get(1)  +  "";
```

But instead of `ids.get(1)` should check every item...eg ids.get(1) OR ids.get(2) OR ids.get(3) ...etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` with a comma-separated list in parens, as in

```
Contacts._ID + " IN(" + TextUtils.join(",", ids) + ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a for loop and execute the query each time:

```
for(int i=1; i<ids.length; i++){
    String select =  Contacts._ID + " = " + ids.get(i)  +  "";
    //execute query
}
```

or are you trying to do this in a single query between 2 values?

```
SELECT Contacts._ID
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Your first alternative would result in ids.size() queries, that's not a good idea.